# Как изменить загрузчик в grub rescue

Tags: linux, grub

Случайно сделал раздел со "сломаной"  ubuntu загрузочной. Флешки или диска с livecd нету,  можно ли как нибудь в grab rescue сделать активным обратно загрузочный раздел который на  windows?

Comment: Можно вызвать редактор конфига прямо из `grub` нажав на клавишу `e`, а после загрузить с учетом исправлений `Ctrl+x`(справедливо для `grub2`)

Comment: `alt+c`  ничего не выводит к сожалению

Comment: Ошибся, исправил комментарий

Comment: Все ровно не работает, может это и маловажно но я не в самом grub, a в grub rescue mode, вот весь текст при попытке загрузится : `error: no such partition. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>`

Comment: Имелось ввиду именно загрузочное меню `grub`, по `grub rescue` ничего сказать не могу

Answer (score 0):

Восстановить загрузчик windows'а прямо из grub rescue не смог, но благодаря инструкции с https://askubuntu.com/a/495993 появилась возможность загрузится в Ubuntu, а оттуда уже решил свою проблему.